# How does the duration of antibiotic course impact gut flora?

Tags: gastroenterology, antibiotics, gut-microbiota-flora

It is well-known that antibiotic use reduces the diversity of natural gut flora.

Have there been any studies that look into how the magnitude of this effect may differ between longer and shorter courses of antibiotics?

E.g., would a 10 day course cause significantly more disruption than a 5 day course, or could most of the significant reduction in diversity have occurred already after a 5 day course?

I'm not expecting a clear answer to the example question, but any research that addresses this in part would be helpful.